# Which lifecycle event to change layout fonts

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin

I have tried changing the typeface of a Textview in one of my activities within the onCreate() event but it does not seem to change the font. Not errors occdured so the font and code seem fine.

Is there somewhere else other than onCreate where I should be doing the call below?

Or, even better is there a way to change to my custom font from within the xaml layoutfile, much like you can do with iOS interface builder? MY layout file properties for the textview only seem to show the basic fonts that come with the system.

Please note the code is c# for xamarin but shouldn't matter...

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Remove title bar
        this.RequestWindowFeature (WindowFeatures.NoTitle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LoginLayout);
        // Create your application here


        Typeface headerTypeFace = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (this.Assets, "fonts/avenir_heavy_webfont.ttf");
        TextView headerTextView = (TextView)this.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);

        headerTextView.SetTypeface (headerTypeFace, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put a code in `Android Studio` (What I'm using) just adapt to `Xamarin` because I never work with it.

First of all I guess you've downloaded a `.tff` and you've created a folder inside the `Assets` named `fonts` and you've placed it inside... right? Then you have to choose your `TextView` and do this :

```
TextView headerTextView = (TextView)this.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);
Typeface type = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/avenir_heavy_webfont.ttf");
headerTextView.setTypeface(type);
headerTextView.setText("test test");
```

### Edit

Try to `setText()` on your `TextView` when you allready defined what `Typeface` you want to use, to see if it's doing good or not.

Comment: Yes I have done that as you can see in my code above. What I was asking was wether it was been done in the right place, i.e. onCreate()

Comment: @JohnCogan Yes, you can do it on your `onCreate()`

Comment: Ok, which is where I am currently doing it but its not changing my textviews font, would there be a reason for this?

Comment: Ok, no difference in my code to yours other than the setText call. My problem was that the font I imported from my designer was so similar to the system one I wasn't noticing the change, had to change the font to something wildly different to see it. Thanks for your time though, will mark yours as answer.

Comment: Thanks but ive changed also the Application.Context.Assets instead of this.assets

Comment: Thanks Skizo, is there a difference between this.Assets and Application.Context.Assets other than scope ?